# PHP: remove regex string from value in array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have an array `$text`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "(This is so cool!)"
    [1] => "look at @[48382669205:275:JAY Z] and @[28940545600:27:Beyonc\303\251]'s page"
    [2] => "@[30042869909:32:Van Jones] on Bowe Bergdahl drama"    
)
```

I want to match delete the @[0-9] text, so my output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "(This is so cool!)"
    [1] => "look at JAY Z and Beyonc\303\251's page"
    [2] => "Van Jones on Bowe Bergdahl drama"    
)
```

I tried a whole bunch of things (preg_replace, etc) but this regex is so tricky I can't get the result I want!  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace `/@\[\d+:\d+:([^\]]+)\]/` with `\1`.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "(This is so cool!)",
    "look at @[48382669205:275:JAY Z] and @[28940545600:27:Beyonc\303\251]'s page",
    "@[30042869909:32:Van Jones] on Bowe Bergdahl drama"    
);

$array = preg_replace('/@\[\d+:\d+:([^\]]+)\]/', '\1', $array);

print_r($array);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (This is so cool!)
    [1] => look at JAY Z and Beyoncé's page
    [2] => Van Jones on Bowe Bergdahl drama
)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/159289)

**Regex Autopsy**:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `@` - *a literal at sign*
- `\[` - *a literal `[` character - you need to escape it as `[` is a regex character*
- `\d+` - *a digit matched 1 to infinity times*
- `:` - *a literal colon sign*
- `\d+` - *a digit matched 1 to infinity times*
- `:` - *a literal colon sign*
- `([^\]]+)` - *a matching group matching any character that isn't a literal `]` character matched 1 to infinity times (meaning it will match until it hits a `]`):*
- `\]` - *a literal `]` character*

Comment: See needed [1] => "look at JAY Z and Beyonc\303\251's page"

Comment: @Brotheyura That's just because escaped characters in `"` are expanded.

Comment: +1, withdrew my answer as I hadn't read the question correctly. No need to duplicate your great work. :)

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could give you another +1. I will be bookmarking this for future reference.

Comment: `array_map` is not mandatory, `preg_replace` works with arrays. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: @M42 Good call - there's absolutely no reason for `array_map` in this code then.

Comment: I guess simply `(.*?)` for the last group would be more readable.

Comment: I don't think so, @h2ooooooo.

Comment: @thg435 [*In this case, there is a better option than making the plus lazy. We can use a greedy plus and a negated character class: `<[^>]+>`. The reason why this is better is because of the backtracking. When using the lazy plus, the engine has to backtrack for each character in the HTML tag that it is trying to match. When using the negated character class, no backtracking occurs at all when the string contains valid HTML code. Backtracking slows down the regex engine.*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not that tricky at all

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "(This is so cool!)",
    "look at @[48382669205:275:JAY Z] and @[28940545600:27:Beyonc\303\251]'s page",
    "@[30042869909:32:Van Jones] on Bowe Bergdahl drama"    
);
$pattern = '#@\[(\d+:){2}(.*?)\]#';

$result[$k] = preg_replace($pattern, "$2", $array);
```

Comment: preg_replace can operate on arrays and return an array.  Using an array rather than a for loop involves less code and runs faster, hence my -1